# How to get streams of data in angular

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I am trying to get a stream of data displaying on my console, but I'm probably not aware of the right tools. If I try to get the data from curl it works fine and looks like this:

```
C:\Users\user>curl localhost:8080/slow/5
5
4
3
2
1
0

C:\Users\user>
```

First I tried to use a standard http get request,

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private ngzone: NgZone
) {
  this.http.get('/slow/5').subscribe(x => console.log(x))
}
```

and this is the error I get after 5 secs:

```
error: Object { error: SyntaxError, text: "5\n4\n3\n2\n1\n0\n" }
```

I tried to use the EventSource method, but that doesn't even manage to connect it. Proxies work fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's HTTP client does currently not support streaming. There was a [feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44143) for this but it was declined. The HTTP client of Angular uses `XMLHttpRequest` internally which does also not support streaming.

If you still want to stream the response data, you will have to use the native `fetch` API which does support streaming. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams).

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mtjmsi?file=src/app/app.module.ts) example where a dummy stream of data is setup using the `of` operator from RxJs.

You can see how that stream of data is subscribed in the `app.component.ts`, in order to print out its values in the console.

Comment: It's a bit different from my case, coz here the stream is already present. In the curl console a value if printed every second, which means that angular needs to listen to the source for 5 secs.